# Switch case with condition

Tags: php, switch-statement

Here always display "That was fast!" Why is this? Why output should not be "That's slooooow"?

```
$totaltime = 12;
switch ($totaltime<=13) {

case 1:
echo "That was fast!";
break;

case 5:
echo "Not fast!";
break;

case 12:
echo "That's slooooow";
break;

case 15:
echo "That's too slooooow";
break;
}
```

Comment: You asked this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/26472879/ no more than an hour ago, and accepted an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26473071/, what now?

Answer (score 1):

You are switching on this:

```
$totaltime<=13
```

which is true, so it comes to `1`, and `1==true` is true, so it 'triggers'.

Don't you mean just this?

```
switch ($totaltime) {

case 1:
echo "That was fast!";
break;

case 5:
echo "Not fast!";
break;

case 12:
echo "That's slooooow";
break;

case 15:
echo "That's too slooooow";
break;
}
```

Comment: nope, i changed case 1 as case 2, but same output

Comment: The point is that you need to remove the comparison! If you change the `1` in a `2`, all you are doing is changing the first 'hit' to `2==true`, and in PHP, this also is the case: ANY true-ish value in a case will 'hit', so the first (only when it's not `''` or `array()` etc) will be the echo you get! Check out the switch WITHOUT the `<=13`.

Answer (score 1):

($totaltime<=13) is evaluated to 1 so that is why you end up in the first case, change code to:

```
$totaltime = 12;
switch ($totaltime) {

case 1:
echo "That was fast!";
break;

case 5:
echo "Not fast!";
break;

case 12:
echo "That's slooooow";
break;

case 15:
echo "That's too slooooow";
break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu are using a conditional for a switch statement.  It should be this:

```
$totaltime = 12;
switch ($totaltime) {

case 1:
echo "That was fast!";
break;

case 5:
echo "Not fast!";
break;

case 12:
echo "That's slooooow";
break;

case 15:
echo "That's too slooooow";
break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
   $totaltime = 12;
    switch ($totaltime) {

case 1:
echo "That was fast!";
break;

case 5:
echo "Not fast!";
break;

case 12:
echo "That's slooooow";
break;

case 15:
echo "That's too slooooow";
break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but i think ($totaltime<=13) is equal true or 1 .you should use only $totaltime.