# Can any one explain Switch Case behaviour?

Tags: php, switch-statement

on all version of php, i have an problem with switch case statement
I can't understand this behaviour =>

```
        $coef = 0;

    switch($coef) {
        case ($coef >= 0 && $coef <= 2.1):
            var_dump( 1);
            break;
        case ($coef > 2.1 && $coef <= 4.1):
            var_dump( 2);
            break;
        case ($coef > 4.1 && $coef <= 6.1):
            var_dump( 3);
            break;
        case ($coef > 6.1 && $coef <= 8.1):
            var_dump( 4);
            break;
    }
```

// Return 2 not 1

So the first condition (coef >= 0 && $coef <= 2.1) => return true;
The second return false: ($coef > 2.1 && $coef <= 4.1) => return false;
The second case always return the result.

To have a normal behaviour we need to write switch case like that :

```
    switch($coef) {
        case ($coef === 0):
        case ($coef > 0 && $coef <= 2.1):
            var_dump( 1);
            break;
        case ($coef > 2.1 && $coef <= 4.1):
            var_dump( 2);
            break;
        case ($coef > 4.1 && $coef <= 6.1):
            var_dump( 3);
            break;
        case ($coef > 6.1 && $coef <= 8.1):
            var_dump( 4);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK, switch case is for fixed expressions, not for conditions. This looks like a really classic use-case for an if-else-chain. Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: "The second case always return the result." That's because `0 == false`. And `0 != true` for the first case. What you need is obviously `switch (true) {}`.

Comment: In such a case (full comparison in the case branches), put true in the switch clause: _switch(true) { ... }_

Comment: Just found this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472879/php-switch-case-statement-with-conditional-switch

Comment: It's a classic error.  Switch/case is not a drop-in replacement for if/else.  The `case` conditions don't look for `true`, they look for the *matching value* to the variable.  The first `case` is `true`, and the value `true` does not match the value `0`.  The second `case` is `false`, and the value `false` *does* match the value `0`.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [PHP- Switch case statement with conditional switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472879/php-switch-case-statement-with-conditional-switch), `switch` always compares the top expression with the result of whatever expression you put into the `case`.

As explained in the link (and by lukas.j), you need to put `true` in your top statement, if you want to stop at the first line which evaluates to `true`.